# imakeidx package - how to insert index in 2-column document?

Tags: imakeidx

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
```

When index was inserted at the end of document, it breaks the two-column layout, when inserted in the beginning - it's not appear.

Is there way to fix it?

Here is example

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Alex Ushakov}
\title{Latex Demo Document}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
% \printbibliography
\listoffigures
\listoftables
% \makeglossaries

\section{demo0}
\lipsum

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\caption{test}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{demo.jpg}
\end{figure}

\subsection{subdemo0}
\lipsum

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{test}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
    \hline
    cell & cell & cell \\
    cell & cell & cell \\
    cell & cell & cell \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{subdemo1}
\lipsum
This is index test\index{test} sentence\index{sentence}.

\section{demo1}
\lipsum

\subsection{subdemo0}
\lipsum

\subsection{subdemo1}
\lipsum

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (MWE).

Comment: I updated the initial post.@heather

Comment: How do you want to fix it? where do you want to print the index?

Comment: In a column, in any document place. But it will not be page-wide.